# C terminal / Wifi thermostat

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I'm using a blue wire as a c-wire, however when I went to connect the blue wire at the furnace, it already had a white wire ( not from a thermostat) corrected to the c-terminal. Can / wires be connected to c terminal? If not, what do I do with the white wire?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an air conditioner? The outside condenser usually gets connected to `Y` and `C` on the control board, and will usually be a control cable with red and white wires (though colors are non-standardized and irrelevant).

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Is it okay for wires at the C terminal to touch?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/61821/33), [Can you terminate more than one common on the furnace C terminal?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/25667/33)

Answer (score 2):

You **can** connect multiple wires to the same C terminal. The other one is likely going to the outside AC unit.